# How to use an interface containing type constraint as generic

Tags: go, generics, type-constraints

I want to have a slice of structs with a generic. The generic is an interface with a type constraint.

```golang
type constraint interface {
    int32 | uint32
}

type a[T constraint] struct {
    something T
}

type b struct {
    as []a[constraint] // doesn't work
}
```

How do I make it so i can use both `a[int32]` and `a[uint32]` as elements in `b.as`?

Comment: You either specify a non generic type for the instantiation, e.g. `as []a[int32]`; or you make the `b` type generic and use the type parameter in the instantiation: https://go.dev/play/p/BeTEslmPSCt

Comment: You cannot make a slice with mixed element types if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

What I am trying to do is not possible in the way I am proposing. This is because `a[int32]` and `a[uint32]` are different types. I need to create an internal interface that only `a` implements and create an array of that.

```golang
type internal interface {
    someObscureMethod()
}

func (anA a[T]) someObscureMethod() {}

type b struct {
    as []internal
}
```